# Length of Assign variable issue in freemarker

Tags: freemarker, smooks

I am using freemarker ..want to find the length of assign variable ..i used size and length function ..but it fails and returns the error ..Please help me in how to find length of the assign variable

Please find the below code i have tried...

Input data --- `cusID="a-1242"` -- I want to split input data by - and want to store in separate variable through assign function

```
 <#list (it.@CusID[0]!"")?split("-") as c><#if ((c?index) ==0)>
<#assign first>${c}</#assign>
<#assign firstlen = c?size>
</#if>
 </#list>
```

Above code `firstlen`  is used to find the length but it fails to find length

ERROR MESSAGES find below

> For "?size" left-hand operand: Expected an extended-hash or sequence
>   or extended collection, but this has evaluated to a markup_output
>   (wrapper: f.c.TemplateXMLOutputModel):

Comment: did you try with length?

Comment: Yes checked with length function also.. It also returns errors..

Comment: BTW, `(it.@CusID[0]!"")?split("-")` can be just written as `it.@CusID[0]!""?split("-")`, which can be just written as `it.@CusID[0]!?split("-")`

Comment: And, `<#if ((c?index) ==0)>` can be written as `<#if  c?index == 0>`. (Before someone says something rude, (: I have also answered the question down below...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, `first` stores XML markup, not just a plain text string. You can't get the length of markup with `?length`, as it's not obvious what that means (like if the content of which XML elements matter, what if you have an entity reference, etc.). The reason it's markup is that `<#assign first>...</#assign>` is not a normal assignment, it's for capturing output, and you are using XML output format. Instead, use normal value assignment: `<#assign first = c>`. Now `first` will have the same type as `c`, string.

Comment: Hi ddekany,Thanks a ton..Your suggestion <#assign first = c> works like a  wonder...Great..Please Share your any freemarker BLOG to learn more if possible..

Comment: Official documentation and StackOverflow is the best source... and https://try.freemarker.apache.org/ can be very handy. Note that you are supposed to "accept" the answer if it solved your issue.